# DIY Windscreen ideas?

Tags: field-recording, wind-protection, windscreens, equipment, microphone

Hi Guys

I recently bought a matched pair of NT5s for field recording and was wondering if anyone has any ideas about how to reduce wind noise as Rode doesn't sell any dead cats or kittens catered for the NT5s.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to http://www.rycote.com/resources/microphone_database/rde_-_nt5/, the Rycote 18/32 SDM Foam (104414) should fit: http://www.rycote.com/products/foam_windscreens/small_diaphragm_mic_foam/

Surely there are similar general purpose foam caps from other manufacturers.

Answer (score 2):

Rycote sell small windshields which the NT5s would fit inside - check their website for NT5 compatible products, or Im sure you could use 2 Rode windshields.

I recently made a windshield which I used with an NT4, ive been meaning to write a guide for a while;

http://www.haydnpayne.com/diy_windshield.htm

Answer (score 0):

Interesting ortf setup with blimp windpack

This could be a valid way to do stereo IF you like the French array.

http://audiofieldrecordings.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/rode-nt5-microphones-modified-ortfnos-recording-technique/